# keeping references to inflated custom views

Tags: android, view

While researching how to create custom compound views in Android, I have come across this pattern a lot (example comes from the [Orange11 blog](http://blog.orange11.nl/2009/10/08/exploring-the-world-of-android-part-3/)) :

```
public class FirstTab extends LinearLayout {
private ImageView imageView;
private TextView textView;
private TextView anotherTextView;

public FirstTab(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstTab, this);
}
```

}

I mostly understand how this is working, except for the part where inflate() is called.  The documentation says that this method returns a View object, but in this example the author does not store the result anywhere.  After inflation, how is the new View created fromt eh XML associated with this class? I thought about assigning it to "this", but that seems very wrong.

thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to *this* would be the viewgroup root. See here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)

What this means is it is inflating the designated view from xml with *this* as the parent view. The xml ends up inside the Linear layout defined by the class.

edit: put in the full link as I can't seem to get URLs with brackets to escape properly